# htaccess url rewrites not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi I have been trying work out how to use htaccess to clean up urls that contain GET parameters and values

From
www.bobbyskennel.co.uk/contact/index.php?page=site-map-page
or
www.bobbyskennel.co.uk/contact/?page=site-map-page

To
www.bobbyskennel.co.uk/contact/site-map-page

So far I have created an .htaccess file and added the rules below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# contact directory sub pages
RewriteRule ^contact/([A-Z­a-z­0-9­-]+)/?$ contact/index.php?page=$1 [L]
# bobby directory sub pages
RewriteRule ^bobby/([A-Z­a-z­0-9­-]+)/?$ bobby/index.php?page=$1 [L]
# petgallery directory sub pages
RewriteRule ^petgallery/([A-Z­a-z­0-9­-]+)/?$ petgallery/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I have placed the file in the root of the site at localhost and tested it and all the rewrites work when I enter a clean url to navigate to a sub page like the site map and cookies and privacy policy pages.

But when I add a slash to the end of the url they fail, yet the ? character in the regex pattern match expression is supposed to mean that the preceeding / at the end of the match pattern is optional and should work with or without a slash, you can check this on the live site.

I have seen lots of examples with two rules one for urls with no slash at the end and another rule for urls without slashes at the end, but this method seems a much better way of achieving the same thing.

I have adjusted the regex but I just end up breaking it, it would be great if I could resolve this issue, any advice or help will be much appreciated.

I forgot to explain how the site is structured, the site is divided using directories which each contain an index.php file and a directory that contains the include files that contain the meta data and content for each page within that section of the site.

A simple controller is stored in the include directory in root and included in each index.php file.

Comment: It does this because `contact/` is an actual directory. I think this could be solved by turning off directory slashes with `DirectorySlash off`.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply I added DirectorySlash off to the htaccess in the local copy under WAMP and tried it but it failed, although gracefully without any dependencies which is better than a 404

Comment: Perhaps an `.htaccess` file in each directory? In it, you'd need to set the `RewriteBase` to the directory path (`/contact/`, for example), and then turn off directory slashes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely wrong here - my original comment was an assumption of sorts (you do not need `DirectorySlash` off, unless requesting the directory without a second URI segment). I have imported your directives onto my dev server, and it appears to be working fine - both with the slash and without it. That said, I would recommend only matching without the trailing slash to ensure there's no duplicate content. You can create a rule to trim out the trailing slash if not requesting a directory.

Comment: Hi Mike I tried the new rules in your answer undwer WAMP locally, but I just got 404 errors without slashes and with, but your comments about me using relative paths for the CSS and JS library files pointed me to the answer, I just added a base url tag to the head section of the index.php where the section contains sub pages. I will just have to remember to adjust them before I move them from WAMP to the live server.

Comment: What I forgot to explain was that my goal here is to make sure all my sites use url's that have the same form as WordPress to make migration easier going forwards, So I can now adjust the navigation links to the sub pages so they end with a slash and its all good.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I do apologise - only looked at your site now. I see your problem - it has nothing to do with the rewriting not working, because it does actually work.

It's the fact the your CSS files are referenced in relation to the current path like this `../`. You need to remove `..` from each of these, which will force the request to be relative to the root of the site. What's happening now as that a request for `/contact/styles/...` (instead of `/styles/...`) will be made when you request `/contact/something/` (with the trailing slash). Here's the fix:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles/bk-layout.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles/bk-pages.css"/>
```

That said, I still recommend looking at my original answer below - it'll save you some time, and keep your site SEO-friendly.

---

Give the following a try:

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Skip direct requests to existing directories and files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Trim trailing slash when not requesting a directory
# (we do not use the condition here as this is already
# covered in the first part above)
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

# Now, check for /{dir}/{slug} and, if {dir} exists,
# rewrite request to /{dir}/index.php?page={slug}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/ -d
RewriteRule ^ /%1/index.php?page=%2 [L]
```

The purpose of this alternative file is to trim out trailing slashes and not allow them when rewriting (this prevents duplicate content, which results in better SEO) and to make the rewriting process easier.

So, the process is this:

1. The first part skips direct requests to existing directories and files. If such request is made, nothing happens from that point, except that the directory or file being requested is served.
2. The second part trims out the trailing slash if the request is not for an existing directory, i.e. `/contact/`. We don't need to use a condition here as the first part already covers the directory-check.
3. This is the fun part. Say a request is made to `/contact/hello`. The first condition checks the request URI, and then passes on the first segment to the second condition, which checks to see if it exists. In this case, it will check to see if `/contact/` exists. If so, it will rewrite to the `index.php` file stored in that directory.

The third point above is just an alternative method that I think will help you considerably as you won't need to add new rules for each directory and index file created.

The second point above is the answer to your question. Generally, when having problems with trailing slashes when they are made optional, the solution is to opt for the non-slash route, and trimming them out too, so that Google doesn't see duplicate content.

<sup>**Note about the temporary redirect:** I've left the trailing slash redirect as 302. Should you decide that you prefer this behaviour, then change it to 301 to make it cachable and permanent.</sup>

Comment: Adding the base url tag has resolved the issue and the rules work as expected to mitigate the duplicate content issue I will add a cannonical tag and load it via a variable in the include file for each page.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike it is much appreciated.